# How to use HREF in ternary operator in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am a junior Laravel developer, and I want to add a ternary operator; if the user logged in, he redirects to the cart. If not, then call modal or redirect to another route.

```
<a {{ Auth::guard('buyer')->check() ? 'href="{{url('/cart')}}"' : href="{{url('/cartempty')}}" }} class="text-gray-90 position-relative d-flex " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cart">
```

Comment: welcome to SO... Please explain what probleme do you face ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="{{ url(Auth::guard('buyer')->check() ? '/cart' : '/cartempty')}}" class="text-gray-90 position-relative d-flex " data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cart">
```